# Tab keypress don't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm using this function, and I'm trying to figure out why the tab button does not work in Firefox. The regex works in others browsers.

```
$('#email').on('keypress', function(event) {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.\b\t]+$");
            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'dont understand why it works, but the problem was solved adding

**if ([0, 8].indexOf(charCode) !== -1) return;**

```
$('#email').on('keypress', function(event) {
            var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.\b]+$");
            var charCode = !event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode;
            console.log([0, 8].indexOf(charCode));
            if ([0, 8].indexOf(charCode) !== -1) return;
            var key = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
```